# Fetching album cover photo

Tags: php, html, facebook-graph-api

I'm using the Graph Api on PHP to fetch the albums for an user.

As I display them, I would like to also show the cover photo for each album. I do get the `[cover_photo]` attribute on each album, but I would like to show that picture without having to make a new request for each photo to get the `source` URL for all of them.

Is there any way to do this?

I tried (without success) to fetch the photos doing the following:

```
<img src="//graph.facebook.com/<?=$album['id'] ?>/picture">
```

I read [a post about it](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7253155/how-to-get-cover-photo-of-album-and-photos-of-the-album-using-fbgraph-api) where the solution is:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/<id>/picture?type=album&access_token=<token>
```

But I can't just put the access_token inside an img src publicly... can I?

Comment: `//graph.facebook.com` would be an invalid url anyways.

Comment: Its a valid URL. Its a protocol relative URL.

Comment: I picked it up from this post: http://paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very conscientious of you to do this. But you need not worry, as any graph api call that uses an access token automagically requires the request to be https.

Another approach: you can log out of your facebook session at the end of the script which will invalidate the access token.

On a related note, facebook does not mention this as being a security risk. They had a problem with leaked access tokens caused by including them in the HTTP request, and also not using HTTPS. Both of these holes are fixed, and non-expriing tokens have also been removed.
https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/497/

Here is a good article explaining the security of the access token since Facebook switched to Oauth 2.0
http://www.sociallipstick.com/?p=239

Answer (score 0):

If you make your access_token public, you want to take precautions such that the user doesn't unknowingly give it to someone else.

Make sure your app communicates across HTTPS, otherwise if your user is browsing your website on public wifi, someone can snoop your traffic and get the access_token. The hack is similar to how [Firesheep](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firesheep) worked.

If a malicious 3rd party gets the user's access_token, he can query Facebook with requests as if he is your app. This could get very nasty if your app has the publish_stream or manage_friendslists permissions.

As long as your user is aware of this, it's fine. The main thing you don't want the user to have is your app's secret key. During the authentication process, your app tells the user's browser to goto Facebook and come back with a "code". Your server then directly connects to facebook (the user's browser doesn't know), and sends that code along with your app's secret key. Facebook comes back to your server with the access token.

Comment: I do understand the OAuth flow. That's why I'm trying to find a solution that doesn't require putting the access_token in the img src.